# Can I use ALAssetsLibrary in test target?

Tags: ios, alassetslibrary

I want to write a unit test and in that test I need to use ALAssetsLibray to fetch items from camera roll.

Tests are not running on device.
If I try to run in simulator, I get this error:

*2015-07-24 11:39:13.558 xctest[2508:43512] error enumerating AssetLibrary groups Error Domain=ALAssetsLibraryErrorDomain Code=-3311 "User denied access" UserInfo=0x7ffea389ae10 {NSLocalizedFailureReason=The user has denied the application access to their media., NSLocalizedDescription=User denied access, NSUnderlyingError=0x7ffea158b040 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (ALAssetsLibraryErrorDomain error -3311.)"}*

How can I accomplish this?

(Duplicate of this old question but it does not have a correct answer: )

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the proper way to do it is to mock the `ALAssetsLibray` objects and return your own mock data as if it was fetched by the assets-library. You just need to unit test your own code and your own methods, there's no need to test that the assets-library is working properly.

Comment: The thing is that production code will use assetURLs from the ALAssetsLibrary (assets-library:// scheme).
And I want to test this on large set of items (from my camera roll).

Comment: Otherwise I need to put images in app bundle for testing purposes and override getting of UIImage from ALAsset.

Comment: @vale4674 even if your code uses asset URLs, you can still have your mock return images. It can even be the same repeating images, since you just need to unit test your code. In case you need to perform some sort of stress testing of the assets library with your code, then it sound more like an integration test that you can only achieve with automation tests on the GUI.